# Load a function of a DLL in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dll

When I want to call some information from a DLL, I was told to use the CallWindowProc command. However, when I use that command, I stuck at the hWnd part.

This is the code:

```
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Any, ByVal wParam As Any, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long
Declare Function d4868activatelog Lib "GSP_stdcall.dll" (ByVal filename As String, functstatus As String) As String
Dim lb As Long, pa As Long
Dim versionString As Long
Dim retValue As Long
Dim vb4868activateLog As Long
Dim vb4868closeLog As Long
Dim vb4868defineDataList As Long
Dim vb4868initProg As Long
Dim vb4868terminate As Long
Dim vb4868getDataListD As Long
Dim vb4868getDataListF As Long
Dim vb4868getDataListI As Long
Dim vb4868getUnits As Long
Dim vb4868isValidParamName As Long
Dim vb4868getErrorMsg As Long
Dim vb4868writeToLog As Long
Dim vb4868run As Long
Dim closeModel As Boolean
Dim loadModelAnsi As Boolean


Sub Foo()
  'Load Library
  lb = LoadLibrary("GSP_stdcall.dll")

gspMdfFilename = "TJET.mxl"

  'start log file
  vb4868activateLog = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868activateLog")

  'stop log file
  vb4868closeLog = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868closeLog")

  'create a data set
  vb4868defineDataList = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868defineDataList")

  'initialize DLL session
  vb4868initProg = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868initProg")
  vb4868terminate = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868terminate")
  vb4868getDataListD = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868getDataListD")
  vb4868getDataListF = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868getDataListF")
  vb4868getDataListI = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868getDataListI")
  vb4868getUnits = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868getUnits")
  vb4868isValidParamName = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868isValidParamName")
  vb4868getErrorMsg = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868getErrorMsg")
  vb4868writeToLog = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868writeToLog")
  vb4868run = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868run")
  vb4868programInfo = GetProcAddress(lb, "d4868programInfo")

  'Call the getVersion function'

  If vb4868programInfo > 0 Then
  about = CallWindowProc(vb4868programInfo, Me.hWnd, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&)
  Else
  MsgBox "Programinfo is not loaded", vbOKOnly
  End If

End Sub

Sub closeDll()

FreeLibrary lb

End Sub
```

When I want to debug this code, I got the error "Invalid use of the keyword Me". I do not have any experience with the CallWindowProc command, and so do I with the hWnd part. What do I have to set at that part? When I do not use the Me, but leave it blanc, VBA stops working, so I think the problem is at that part of the code.

Comment: Did you try Application.Hwnd?

Comment: Yes, it will crash VBA as well.

Comment: CallWindowProc is for window subclassing in the Windows UI.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think not, I want to recieve the information that is inside the function, I only do not know how to get this and how to show it. I found an example somewhere where they used CallWindowProc, so I also used it, because I thought that was how to recieve the information.

Comment: The DLL library you are using should have its own method for that.  I'm not familiar with that particular library, but it should be in the documentation.

Comment: Is the code that you use in a Standard Module, or a Class Module?

Comment: Also, do you know which window to you want to message? If yes, put the handle of that window as parameter to your `CallWindowProc` call.